# Apache visit abc.com/api/xxx auto rewrite to api.com/api.php

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

When I visit localhost/api/xxx auto rewrite to localhost/api.php, how to cancel this role? I can't find this rewrite conf.

I also check the .htaccess file and clear it , but that doesn't work.

Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) option enabled. You can turn it off by placing the following line in your `.htaccess` file.

```
Options -MultiViews
```